# Error message if I'm using IntegerField for one of the form field

Tags: python, authentication, flask, integer, field

I have an IntegerField in my login Form and it throws me an error of unsuccessful login message on submit. Although when I change IntegerField to StringField it works fine and validates the the login. Is there any way how to get IntegerField also validate on submit.

**this is my route code**

```
@app.route("/login", methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def login():
    form = LoginForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        if form.username.data == 'User' and form.code.data == '1234':
            flash(f'Book your time {form.username.data}', 'secondary')
            return redirect(url_for('booking'))
        else:
            flash('Login Unsuccessful. Please check your name and the code', 'danger')
    return render_template('login.html', title='Login', form=form)
```

**this is my forms.py file**

```
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField, IntegerField, SubmitField
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired, Length, NumberRange


class LoginForm(FlaskForm):
    username = StringField('Name', validators=[DataRequired(), Length(min=2, max=20)])
    code = IntegerField('Code', validators=[DataRequired(), NumberRange(min=1, max=9999)])
    submit = SubmitField('Book time')
```

**this is my login.html file**

```
<main class="form-signin">
    <form method="POST" action="">
        {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
        <img class="mb-4" src="{{ url_for ('static', filename='img/vertical.png') }}" alt="" width="100">
        <div class="form-floating">
            {{ form.username.label(class="form-lable") }}
            {% if form.username.errors %}
                {{ form.username(class="form-control form-control-lg is-invalid") }}
                <div class="invalid-feedback">
                    {% for error in form.username.errors %}
                        <span>
                            {{ error }}
                        </span>
                    {% endfor %}
                </div>
            {% else %}
                {{ form.username(class="form-control") }}
            {% endif %}
        </div>
        <div class="form-floating">
            {{ form.code.label(class="form-lable") }}
            {% if form.code.errors %}
                {{ form.code(class="form-control is-invalid") }}
                <div class="invalid-feedback">
                    {% for error in form.code.errors %}
                        <span>
                            {{ error }}
                        </span>
                    {% endfor %}
                </div>
            {% else %}
                {{ form.code(class="form-control") }}
            {% endif %}
        </div>
        <div class="form-floating">
            {{ form.submit(class="w-100 btn btn-lg btn-primary") }}
        </div>

        <div class="bottom_link">
            <a class="link-primary" href="{{url_for('booking')}}">See available bookings</a>
        </div>
    </form>
</main>
```

Comment: Are you sure that `form.code.data == '1234'` shouldn't be `form.code.data == 1234` ?

Comment: Sure it shouldn't be with quotes, thanks for that